# How do I displace only outside of cylinder and exclude interior of cylinder mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv, subdivision-surface, displacement, vertex-groups

Hi I have a question I want to make a textured roller in in Blender
I followed a video tutorial  (link below) when I get to subdivide and create a vertex group to assign the displacement image it affects the outside of the cylinder but also the inside of the cylinder which I want smooth I don't know how to separate the inside from being affected by the displacement image. I have an online folder with all the screenshots what it should look like and what I get. I included the blend work file and exported  blend file as well as the displacement image at my online file account.

3D Printable Textured Rolling Pin Tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyWY26Dd8R8

Work files and screenshot explanations located here :

My shared folder:
https://www.mediafire.com/folder/mn8b59dxzsl74/TEXTUREROLLERWOODFLOOR

Comment: your problem my be that you've given a Solidify modifier to your object, so the inner faces will be affected the same way as the outter faces, so I guess you need to apply the Solidify, and remove the inner faces from the vertex group?

Comment: Thanks moonboots I will try your method and let you know. Appreciate your help. Maybe more questions to come. Mike

Comment: Hello I found the solution the  version of blender 2.9 didn't have the apply button for the solidify modifier I reinstalled version 2.8 the vertex problem of separating it from the inside is solved now that the apply button for the solidify modifier is visible.thanks for your help.

Comment: you have an apply button, it's the down arrow on the top of the modifier, or select the modifier and press Ctrl A

Answer (score 3):

- Create your cylinder with a reasonable amount of subdivision, (which will eventually separate vertex groups), and give it 2 vertex groups; mine are called 'Shell' and 'Rim', for convenience. You don't need to allocate to them: they're placeholders.

[image]

- Give the cylinder a *Solidify* modifier. In the modifier there's an 'Output Vertex Groups' section. There, you can set 'Shell' to Shell, and 'Rim' to Rim.
  The resulting 'Shell' vertex group is shown on the left, 'Rim' on the right.

[image]

- In this case, using a *Vertex Weight Mix* modifier, I added the 'Shell' group to the 'Rim' group. This was to isolate a region (the blue one, below) from the rim, which would displace more neatly. I have a *Bevel* (by angle) modifier below the *Solidify*, to harden the edges of the rim of the roller.

[image]

- Now, you can aim the Displacement at the *inverse* of the mixed group, (using the little double arrow) to displace only in that outside region.

[image]

With this sort of result:

[image]

This keeps all your modifiers live. But, as @moonboots has commented, it may be simpler, for this project, to work more destructively, applying modifiers as you go along.

Comment: Thanks Robin I will try your method and let you know. Appreciate your help. Maybe more questions to come. Mike

Comment: @mnoona Sure.. if you don't get bits of this answer, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Hi Robin I found the solution the  version of blender 2.9 didn't have the apply button for the solidify modifier I reinstalled version 2.8 the vertex problem of separating it from the inside is solved now that the apply button for the solidify modifier is visible.thanks for your help.

Comment: @mnoona in 29x the apply button is in the dropdown (the little down-chevron) at the end of the bar immediately to the right of the modifer's name.